# Hash sum mismatch error while installing node js and npm

Tags: apt, 20.04, nodejs, npm

```
Err:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:162899 [weak]
   - SHA256:9f4ffba2a05dc2fb76857d4b30ed55724fe6e2999341694f2b86940ab067a44b
   - SHA1:f470f9b518e5cd213a66334f3a5e3b671c4dbe61 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:504d24e4682a64a0559d13f7cf1e5ca6 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:0d49809352ede8d21c648de700d0d16fe10c2394064b1bc457331e0565419e3a
   - SHA1:fd8bebb3573711be3d667718e13250cd7ae6b629 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:747cd4f065cae49a271e9b46cc88c6d6 [weak]
   - Filesize:162899 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Mon, 20 Apr 2020 09:35:48 +0000
  Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

 E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/dep11/by-hash/SHA256/9f4ffba2a05dc2fb76857d4b30ed55724fe6e2999341694f2b86940ab067a44b  Hash Sum mismatch
       Hashes of expected file:
        - Filesize:162899 [weak]
        - SHA256:9f4ffba2a05dc2fb76857d4b30ed55724fe6e2999341694f2b86940ab067a44b
        - SHA1:f470f9b518e5cd213a66334f3a5e3b671c4dbe61 [weak]
        - MD5Sum:504d24e4682a64a0559d13f7cf1e5ca6 [weak]
       Hashes of received file:
        - SHA256:0d49809352ede8d21c648de700d0d16fe10c2394064b1bc457331e0565419e3a
        - SHA1:fd8bebb3573711be3d667718e13250cd7ae6b629 [weak]
        - MD5Sum:747cd4f065cae49a271e9b46cc88c6d6 [weak]
        - Filesize:162899 [weak]
       Last modification reported: Mon, 20 Apr 2020 09:35:48 +0000
       Release file created at: Thu, 23 Apr 2020 17:33:17 +0000
    E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried all the possible solutions provided in other answers and still, the problem exists.
I am using ubuntu 20.04. I am new to Linux environment, so I don't have much knowledge in Linux systems and terminology.

I was trying to install node js and npm. I faced many problems with the apt-get.

problems:

1. npm command was not found after installing using apt-get

   ```
   Command 'npm' not found, did you mean:

     command 'apm' from snap atom (1.48.0)
     command 'nsm' from snap nift (2.3.10)

   See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
   ```
2. when I tried to install `sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`

   I got,

   ```
    Reading package lists... Done
       Building dependency tree       
       Reading state information... Done
       Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
       requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
       distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
       or been moved out of Incoming.
       The following information may help to resolve the situation:

       The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        python-software-properties : Depends: python (>= 2.7) but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: python (< 2.8) but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: python-apt (>= 0.6.20ubuntu16) but it is not going to be installed
                                     Depends: python-pycurl but it is not going to be installed
       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```
3. when I tried to install npm separately using `apt-get npm`

   ```
      The following packages have unmet dependencies:
        npm : Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
   ```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please refine your question and information provided? What command actually led to the first output you provided? What were the other errors / warnings prior to that? It is marked as `Err:37`. I'm not sure the Icons package is what failed you, but I can state that I just manually downloaded the archive file and the hashes were correct according to the release file when I calculated them. Something in you OS / network must have changed the file.

Comment: Also: have you tried to manually install node-gyp? Have you manually tried to change / reinstall python in the past? Have you tried to browse with your browser to the repository and manually download and install your packages?

Comment: Actually the icons 64x64 package caused the error at line 37

Comment: I tried downloading manually, but I don't know how to do it correctly after downloading the file. Can you Instruct me the steps for doing it? I figured out that it was causing problems while installing nodejs.

Comment: with no options left I reinstalled the Ubuntu OS. Eventually, all these errors appear when I do apt-get update. Actually I am using a dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows. Is there any way to resolve this... I am a newbie to Linux

Comment: After reinstalling the whole os you still receive those problems? To manually install the package, you can simply double click your package (if you're using the desktop version) and let your package manager to install it for you. You can also do this using the terminal with the command `dpkg --install` and package name.

Comment: No after reinstalling ubuntu , I installed vscode and android studio and a few other tools. at first apt-get update was running good, but after some time when I ran apt-get before installing node js I got the error again. I tried changing all the mirror locations, nothing worked. Moreover in software updater, the dialogue box updating cache was stuck and was not closing. I killed it through system monitor

Comment: The package I downloaded has this kind of file name: "9f4ffba2a05dc2fb76857d4b30ed55724fe6e2999341694f2b86940ab067a44b.gz". This is the hash that was shown as the mismatched one

Comment: Oh I meant you should manually download and install the npm package from the repository. Navigate to your repository pool via web browser (for example: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/ ) and search for your package. If you do not know which one to download, use this command: `apt-policy your_package_name`. It'll show you the best package candidate that fits your os. Also, while your downloaded file is not needed, you may still use the command `sha256sum` on your file to check if the hash did not change when it was downloaded to your machine.

Comment: I tried it, I don't understand what that is...btw is there any solution to fix the hash sum mismatch...fixing that would fix my problem...i tried clearing the cache,lists and everything and but apt update always gives the error as I mentioned above

Comment: I figured out the problem...it was my internet connection...when I connected to my mobile data..it was flawless.... idk what was the problem with my internet..

Comment: It is good practice, as now you've just learnt why hash sums are important: aside of package integrity check, your package manager also makes sure the package is not corrupt. If you found your solution, consider self answering your question and accepting your answer so the question will tag as solved for other users.

Comment: yeah sure! thanks for your help! well appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem...it was my internet connection...when I connected to my mobile data(or any other internet service)..it was flawless...

If the hash sum error persists after trying many solutions try changing your internet connection. I believe it applies some network filters which changes the hash.